# How to router angular 6 cascading dropdown?

Tags: angular, path, nested, dropdown, router

When I select City after than select District Showing places below. I'm getting data from an array.

I want to add routing url like website.com/city/down or website.com/city-down when select city after district.

I tried with jquery and vue but I can't. How can I do?

home.html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" class="province-menu">
  <option [ngValue]="null" selected>City</option>
    <option *ngFor="let cities of city" [ngValue]="cities" 
[disabled]="cities.disable">
      {{ cities.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <select class="district-menu" [(ngModel)]="selectedDown" >
    <option [ngValue]="null" selected>Down</option>
    <option *ngFor="let dw of selectedCity.down" [ngValue]="dw" [disabled]="dw.disable">
    {{dw.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

home.ts

```
{'name':'City',
'value':1,
'down':[
  {'name':'Down',
  'value':1_1,
  'places':[
    {'name':'DownPlaces01'},
    {'name':'DownPlaces02'}  ]}]}
selectedCity = this.city[0];

  selectedDown = this.selectedCity.down[0];

 selectedPlaces = this.selectedDown.places[0];
```

Comment: could you explain more on what you want to achieve?  From your question, it is not that clear.

Comment: @Amir I explained more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you exactly want to do and why you've mentioned Vue and jQuery in Angular question, but this might help:

In your html file you can add `ngModelChange` handler to both dropdowns, it can look like this:

```
<select
[(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
(ngModelChange)="onCitySelect($event)"
class="province-menu">
    <option [ngValue]="null" selected>City</option>
    <option
    *ngFor="let cities of city"
    [ngValue]="cities"
    [disabled]="cities.disable">
        {{ cities.name }}
    </option>
</select>

<select
[(ngModel)]="selectedDown"
(ngModelChange)="onDistrictSelect($event)"
class="district-menu">
    <option [ngValue]="null" selected>Down</option>
    <option
    *ngFor="let dw of selectedCity.down"
    [ngValue]="dw"
    [disabled]="dw.disable">
        {{dw.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

and your `home.ts`:

```
onCitySelect(city) {
    this.selectedCity = city;
    this.selectedDown = null;
}

onDistrictSelect(district) {
    this.selectedDown = district;
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`city/${this.selectedCity}/${this.selectedDown}`);
}
```

Comment: issue on quotes and code doesn't work. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-cxkwv6 I work here. Can you check it?

Comment: @ucnumara There was a little typo - I edited my original post and here you go with stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-cxkwv6-seybr4

Comment: are you sure it work ? Nothing changed. Same as at the beginning

Comment: Yes, value in both selects changes according to your selected city and application is aware of this changes. The only thing that is left, is to setup whole router and routing and add component that will handle those new city routes.

Comment: add "import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';"
to home.component.ts but still nothing changed

Comment: I can’t recommend enough the official docs, they cover almost everything: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5 . If you prefer more traditional tutorial, you can look here: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router/ . Let me know if you succeed.